# Homologation Process in Biztalk 2013

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have some messages that require an Homologation process. The homologation data is in a SQL server database table that has two fields, one for lookup the field and the other for the value. I want to do it without hard-code the string connection (that's why I didn't use DataBase functoids in Mapping).

Answer (score 1):

Having the connection string hardcoded is considered a bad practice when using the Database Lookup Functoid. Good news is that you don't have to...
Take a look at [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547392.aspx) and head to the 'Best Practices' paragraph where is demonstrated how to use a Scripting Functoid in conjunction to load the connection string.

Also, take a look at the [Blogical Database Functoid](http://blogicalfunctoids.codeplex.com/) with integrated caching and the possibility to load the connection string directly from the BizTalk config file.